# Does a MySQL table require an auto-incrementing ID?

Tags: php, mysql

So normally when I create new tables I'd have a column called `id` set to the primary and set it to auto-increment.

In a new project I'm working on, for each row I need a unique id of a specific length, 15 characters in this case.

So my question, is there an issue with using this 15 character numerical id in place of an auto-incrementing id? Is there a technical reason for using an auto-incrementing number?

I use this to generate the IDs, so as far as I'm aware they're guaranteed to be unique:

```
$randNum = preg_replace('/[.:]/', '', time().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).randomNumber(4)

function randomNumber($length) {
    $result = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Better algorithm?

```
$randNum = round(microtime(true) * 1000).randomNumber(7)

function randomNumber($length) {
    $result = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It's convenient but not necessary. However note that although you might not run into duplicates, your ID generator does not guarantee unique id's.

Comment: No, there is no reason to have an id with auto increment. Only it is better to have a Primary key. They is unique, very fast. Only if you use ie. MariaDB Galera Cluster you must have a Primary key. Over this key the Data are replicatet to the other nodes.

Comment: Theoretically if you have a few (thousand?) requests arriving in the same second (which is pretty long in computer time), you can easily have duplicates.

Comment: php has the `uniqid()` function, I'll let you guess what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not required by MySQL to have an auto-incrementing ID column. However, as [noted in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-database-structure.html), an index key is essential to good database design. If you're manually generating the ID instead of using auto-increment, that's fine, but make sure that the algorithm you use to generate IDs **always** generates unique IDs (which is not the case with algorithm you posted).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a technical reason for using an auto-incrementing number?

`Auto Increment` ID are also known as `synthetic key columns` which are auto generated by the system and make sure that they are unique. It's not mandatory to have auto ID as `primary key`. You can define a column as primary key with your own key values unless they make sure to be unique.

> for each row I need a unique id of a specific length, 15 characters in
>   this case.

In this case, don't define it to be `AUTO INCREMENT` and make it a `VARCHAR(15)` column and say for example if you are populating data from your application and say for example it's a `.NET/C#` application you can use `GUID` as that primary key (OR) some other key to that matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have an auto-incremented id in your table. You can use the id you are creating as the primary key. As for your `randomNumber()` function: as I'm sure you know, there is no guarantee that the numbers will be different, just a very very good chance.  If you want to use it, you should add a check to see if that number exists in your database already

Answer (score 0):

In general, every table in your database should have a primary key.  It can either be an auto incrementing id column or a unique identifier that naturally occurs in your data, or some other method of generating a unique identifier (such as a guid)

MySQL doesn't actually require a primary key at all, but omitting one is generally a **very** bad idea.